# How to use google assistant for enterprises android application without upload the playstore and how to use google assistant api for this?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api, app-actions

I am implementing an enterprise android application and they are providing their app through their Website, not from Google Play Console.
Is this possible to use google assistant API for my enterprise android application?. I found google assistant API are used for embedded things. I want how to use for android application.
How is Google Actions and dialog flow (AI) API working for my requirement?

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview) docs state:

> You can't launch commercial devices that integrate with the Google Assistant SDK. It's available for experimental and non-commercial uses only.

The [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/terms-of-service) go into more detail on usage of the API.

But the Google Assistant SDK is different from using Dialogflow. If you want to integrate your Dialogflow agent in your app, not the Google Assistant, you can start by visiting the [Dialogflow API guide](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/api) to see how to send data to the API to detect intents and obtain responses from your agent.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is related to App Actions specifically. This feature is not currently available. Please stay tuned for any future changes in this respect.